# Trying to install GitHub Copilot in VisualStudio 2022 but failing

Tags: visual-studio, github

**I've signed up for the trial and can find it in the extensions. But when you need to close VS and reopen again, I get a message from VSIX Installer "The install of 'GitHub Copilot' was not successful for all the selected products."
Here's the install log:**

12/07/2023 11:41:26 - Microsoft VSIX Installer 12/07/2023 11:41:26 -
------------------------------------------- 12/07/2023 11:41:26 - vsixinstaller.exe version: 12/07/2023 11:41:26 - 17.5.4074+g1de9468fa7 12/07/2023 11:41:26 - ------------------------------------------- 12/07/2023 11:41:26 - Command line parameters: 12/07/2023 11:41:26 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Community,/skuVersion:17.5.33530.505,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022,/culture:en-US,/noep,C:\Users\SashaRadkova\AppData\Local\Temp\VSIX1aga2clf.vsix 12/07/2023 11:41:26 - ------------------------------------------- 12/07/2023 11:41:26 - Microsoft VSIX Installer 12/07/2023 11:41:26 -
------------------------------------------- 12/07/2023 11:41:26 - Initializing Install... 12/07/2023 11:41:26 - Extension Details... 12/07/2023 11:41:26 -  Identifier         : GitHub.Copilot 12/07/2023 11:41:26 -   Name               : GitHub Copilot 12/07/2023 11:41:26 -   Author             : GitHub 12/07/2023 11:41:26 -   Version            : 1.94.0.0 12/07/2023 11:41:26 -     Description        : GitHub Copilot is an AI pair programmer that helps you write code faster and with less work. Requires Visual Studio 2022 17.5.5 or later. 12/07/2023 11:41:26 -    Locale             : en-US 12/07/2023 11:41:26 -    MoreInfoURL        :  12/07/2023 11:41:26 -     InstalledByMSI     : False 12/07/2023 11:41:26 -    SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647] 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -  SignatureState     : ValidSignature 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -   SignedBy           : GitHub, Inc. 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -     Certificate Info   :  12/07/2023 11:41:27
------------------------------------------------------- 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -       [Subject]       : CN="GitHub, Inc.", O="GitHub, Inc.", L=San Francisco, S=California, C=US 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -        [Issuer]   : CN=DigiCert Trusted G4 Code Signing RSA4096 SHA384 2021 CA1, O="DigiCert, Inc.", C=US 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -        [Serial Number] : 0ED17E3276477EECDEDE0A65744ABC0E 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -        [Not Before]  : 10/02/2023 01:00:00 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -       [Not After]     : 14/02/2024 00:59:59 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -         [Thumbprint]    : 0C5C3D5588A23CC0B287C00262D03CC3F6F4A7FB 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -    Supported Products :  12/07/2023 11:41:27 -         Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -          Version : [17.5.33627,18.0) 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -           ProductArchitecture : amd64 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -   References         :  12/07/2023 11:41:27 -     Prerequisites      :  12/07/2023 11:41:27 -         ------------------------------------------------------- 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -       Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -       Name         : IntelliCode 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -        Version      : [17.4.33213,18.0) 12/07/2023 11:41:27 - Signature Details... 12/07/2023 11:41:27 -   Extension is signed with a valid signature. 12/07/2023 11:41:27 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.    at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)    at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)    at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.ComputeInstallableExtensions(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported, Boolean isExtensionPack, IDictionary`2 skuDataMapping, IList`1 installableExtensionsPaths)    at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)    at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

**Do I understand it correctly that the latest version of CoPilot only works on VS 17 and 18?
Is there a way to get it to work without downgrading VS?
Thanks.**